# why jinja2's function FileSystemLoader() doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, jinja2

I'm following a tutorial about jinja2 library in real python, but every time I use a `Filesystem Loader()` function an error raise that say

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\m00n\Desktop\jinja\write_messages.py", line 12, in <module>
    template = environment.get_template("message.txt")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\m00n\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\m00n\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\m00n\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load    
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\m00n\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 204, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: message.txt
```

I thought that the problem was with python virtual environment so I try to exit it but it didn't work
this is my python code

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

max_score = 100
test_name = "Python Challenge"
students = [
    {"name": "Sandrine",  "score": 100},
    {"name": "Gergeley", "score": 87},
    {"name": "Frieda", "score": 92},
]

environment = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("templates/"))
template = environment.get_template("message.txt")

for student in students:
    filename = f"message_{student['name'].lower()}.txt"
    content = template.render(
        student,
        max_score=max_score,
        test_name=test_name
    )
    with open(filename, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as message:
        message.write(content)
        print(f"... wrote {filename}")
```

and this is the message.txt

```
{# templates/message.txt #}

Hello {{ name }}!

I'm happy to inform you that you did very well on today's {{ test_name }}.
You reached {{ score }} out of {{ max_score }} points.

See you tomorrow!
Anke
```

Comment: maybe you have to use `"/full/path/to/templates/"`. OR maybe you have two folders `templates` - you put `message.txt` in one `template` but code searchs it in different `templates` (in different folder)

Comment: thank you very much, I retry today and the problem was with "code" tag in terminal, when I was using it to create (message.txt) it wasn't creating it in the templates folder even when I'm in templates for some reason, so I have to create it manually.

Comment: frankly, I don't understand what means `"code" tag in terminal` - do you use some IDE? As for me it is natural that I have to create file manually in correct folder. I never saw IDE which creates file automatically in folder `templates`

Comment: it's a way to open a file or create one just using the visual studio code terminal with out a need to file explorar, and it's done by writing "code" then the file name you want to open or create in the folder that you are in, and I was in the path that ends with a templates folder but because of bug or maybe something I didn't understand all the files that I was creating was going to another "templates" folder in another path, so you was right, and I meant by creating files manually, using the explorer in the left side of (visual studio code) screen.